# How one uses level sensor?

Tags: arduino, level

I have bought a [level sensor](http://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?country=be&lang=en&id=348687). I cannot find any documentation except this on the linked page. How do I use it with Arduino or anything else?

[image]

Comment: It's a magnet in a moving float and a fixed reed switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to behave as a Switch. One side can be connected to 5V(logic High), and other as an input to the Digital Pin of your Arduino.
Also remember it says its a NC so the input to the micro will be HIGH by default, if the level is reached it opens and would give a Logic LOW at the input.

Also remember to connect a resistor, or the best way to use it would be a connecting it via a Pull up resistor. Something like this: http://www.cooking-hacks.com/skin/frontend/default/cooking/images/catalog/documentation/tutorial_squidbee_y_squidbee_gateway/analog_sensor_1.png   but digital in your case.

EDIT: Please also read what Dzarda has added in the comments.

Comment: I'd add that the input has to have it's pullup enabled. **EDIT:** No, the other way. I'd connect one side to GND and feed the other side to MCU's pullup-enabled input.

Comment: Dzarda is correct. If the switch is tied to +5 it needs a pull-down resistor, if tied to ground it needs a pull-up.

Answer (score 2):

It's a liquid level float switch which uses a magnet in the round white float to activate a reed switch in the  black part of the switch.

It's designed to be mounted vertically, and whether it's normally open or normally closed will depend on whether you mount it with the leads up or with the leads down.

If the mounting arrangement isn't liquid-tight, then it'll need to be mounted leads-up, so it's probably normally-closed in that position.  Continuity test the switch to find out for sure.

To use it, you pull one contact of the switch up or down with a resistor, connect a digital input to that contact, and then connect the other contact of the swich to the opposite rail the resistor is connected to.

Answer (score -1):

The ultrasonic liquid level sensor emits an ultrasonic pulse, and the sound wave is reflected by the liquid surface and converted into an electric signal by the ultrasonic receiver, and the distance between the sensor and the surface of the liquid to be measured is calculated from the time between the emission and reception of the sound wave. If there is an obstacle under the position where the liquid level sensor is installed, then the ultrasonic level sensor is not suitable. The obstacle will affect the ultrasonic emission and cause signal loss; the obstacles need to be adjusted or avoided. Ultrasonic liquid level sensor is more expensive, non-contact measurement, liquid viscosity, corrosive and other issues will not affect, more sanitary.